# How to get the same date of the previous month?

Tags: oracle, plsql

What I have tried:

```
for i in 1..5 loop
  v_input_date := ADD_MONTHS(v_input_date, -1);
end loop;
```

Results:

```
29.03.2021.
28.02.2021.
31.01.2021.
31.12.2020.
30.11.2020.
```

Expected results:

```
29.03.2021.
28.02.2021.
29.01.2021.
29.12.2020.
29.11.2020.
```

I could extract the day returned, compare it to the original, and decrease it if needed, but is there a better way how to achieve this?

Comment: What is your input_date? Is it `29.03.2021`?

Comment: It is `29.04.2021.`

Comment: I just run your code on fiddle and it is working fine except just change the 1 to I in for loop. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=55ea994516feb6dd0cf446f5f8c5cbe8

Comment: @AnkitBajpai That's not the only change - you also changed it to subtract months from a fixed starting date, rather than iteratively updating a variable one month at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code you posted actually doesn't do what you described.

```
SQL> declare
  2    v_input_date date := date '2021-04-29';
  3  begin
  4    for i in 1 .. 5 loop
  5      dbms_output.put_line(add_months(v_input_date, -1 * i));
  6    end loop;
  7  end;
  8  /
29.03.2021
28.02.2021
29.01.2021
29.12.2020
29.11.2020

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: That isn't the original code, to be fair.

Comment: It wasn't supposed to be, @William. My idea was to post *something* that produces "expected result".

Comment: I was referring to *"Code you posted actually doesn't do what you described."* But that was unfair, as the code in the question does do exactly what the OP described.

Comment: Hahaha! Right! That makes sense :)